# Using Chaco in Python 3.6 (Anaconda)

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, chaco

I'm here because I've tried to install the Chaco module on Anaconda and it doesn't work. First I've tried the simple command:

```
conda install -c anaconda chaco=4.5.0
```

but it returns package specification problems:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - chaco 4.5.0* -> enable 4.5.1 -> numpy 1.10* -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package
```

Then I tried with the Python 2.7 version of Anaconda, but I still have problems with PyQt4 which was uninstalled because of PyQt5.
I created an environement in PyQt4 but the module was still not found. 
I wish I could work with Chaco in Python 3.6 but I don't know what to do...

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda does not currently provide Chaco packages for Python 3. The latest version of Chaco supported by Anaconda is 4.5: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/chaco

As you can see here, Python 3 support wasn't added to Chaco until version 4.6 in December of 2016: https://github.com/enthought/chaco/releases/tag/4.6.0

You can install Chaco in Python 3.6 using `pip install chaco`, but you'll also need numpy, setuptools, enable, and likely Visual Studio.

I'm not sure why you're having difficulty installing Chaco on a Python 2.7 Anaconda environment, but Enable doesn't support PyQt 5, you'll have to use PyQt 4: https://github.com/enthought/enable#prerequisites

Comment: Does anyone know if Continuum has plans to bring Chaco v4.6 into the Anaconda fold?